# Error in accessing Oracle Database from .net class library

Tags: c#, oracle

When I am trying to connect to an Oracle database, a `System.TypeInitializationException` occurs. Error log is shown below. What is the reason to this error and how can I fix this?

- Visual Studio 2017
- Oracle.DataAccess.Dll (Version=4.112.1.2)
- TargetFramework : 4.7.2

Error:

> Message: HandlingInstanceID: 946dd3d7-f9b6-458e-9335-340e8ab9f359
>
> An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred and was caught.
>
> Type : System.TypeInitializationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>   Message : The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter' threw an exception.
>   Source : Oracle.DataAccess
>   TypeName : Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter
>   Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
>   TargetSite : Void .ctor(System.String, Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType)
>   HResult : -2146233036
>
> Stack Trace :
>
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter..ctor(String parameterName, OracleDbType oraType)
>   at Common.DataAccess.Interface.DataRequest.AddParameter(String name, DbType dbt, ParameterDirection direction, Object value, Int32 parameterSize)
>   at DataProviders.RetrievalProviders.LoginProvider.Login(object filter) in E:\DataProviders\RetrievalProviders\LoginProvider.cs:line 27
>
> Additional Info:
>
> MachineName : ANDRIOD-DEV-SVR
>   TimeStamp : 6/8/2020 12:12:44 PM
>   FullName : Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
>   AppDomainName : GUAgent.Service.exe
>   ThreadIdentity :
>   WindowsIdentity : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
>
> Inner Exception
>
> Type : Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.1.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
>   Message : The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client
>   Source : Oracle Data Provider for .NET
>   Errors : Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleErrorCollection
>   DataSource :
>   Procedure :
>   Number : -11
>   ErrorCode : -2147467259
>   Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
>   TargetSite : Void Initialize()
>   HResult : -2147467259
>
> Stack Trace :
>
> at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize()
>   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter..cctor()

Comment: Did you read this?? **Message : The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client**

Comment: Your ODP.NET is version 4.112.1.2. That means your Oracle Client has to be version 11.2. Ensure ODP.NET and the Oracle Client have the same architecture (i.e. 32-bit vs. 64-bit)